# Render partial with coffeescript

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, coffeescript

I'm trying to trigger a partial reload in the drag & drop UI when an element is released. The following code resides in my `projects.js.coffee` file. I'm not sure how to dynamically trigger reordering (last row). Thanks.

```
jQuery ->
  $('#requirements-list').sortable
    axis: 'y'
    update: ->
      $.post($(this).data('update-url'), $(this).sortable('serialize'))
      $("#requirements-list").html('<%= j(render("projects/requirements")) %>');
```